# width of content/footer stopping short of browser width

Tags: html, css, width

The page in question is located at [www.codykrauskopf.com/circus](http://www.codykrauskopf.com/circus)

If you look at the right side of my page there is a gap between the semi transparent container and the edge of the browser window. I looked and for some reason wrap, main, content, and footer all stop short. I've set width of html, body, main, content, wrap, and footer all to 100% with no luck.

```
html, body {height: 100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:auto;
}

#wrap {
width:100%;}
/* Circus.html content*/
#circusContent{
margin-left:100px;

}

p{
font-family:georgia;
}

div.topButtons{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:15px;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
width:130px;
background: rgb(166, 166, 166); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(166, 166, 166, .5); 
}
#leftTopButton{
margin-left:75px;
}
a.forms{
text-decoration:underline;
}

div.topButtons:hover{
background: rgb(100, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
}

#circusParagraph{

color:white;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:125px;
margin-top:25px;
}

#content{
position:relative;

margin-left:22.513089005%;

margin-bottom:-35px;
width:77.486910998%;

background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}

#main,
#wrap,
#content,
#circusContent{
height:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your culprit is:

```
#foottext {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

the `left: 20px` is forcing the div to extend outside of its container which is causing the gap.

instead of moving or rearranging large elements on your page with `position: relative` you will probably have better results applying padding or margin.

Comment: And it gets rid of my the horizontal scroll bar. You my friend are awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Take out

max-width: 120em; for your main container

That should solve your problem